# Member overrides obsolete member Error when using ShouldOverrideUrlLoading in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

I am a amateur coder trying to play around and explore. My coding levels is pretty novice. I have been trying to build a simple app in Xamarin. All it consist of is a webView which loads my website. Thats it. When I try to build I am getting the following error which I cannot seem to find an answer for. Can someone please help?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   CS0672  Member
>   'MainActivity.HelloWebViewClient.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView,
>   string)' overrides obsolete member
>   'WebViewClient.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, string)'. Add the
>   Obsolete attribute to
>   'MainActivity.HelloWebViewClient.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView,
>   string)'. pnbApp  D:\Workspace\PNB_App\pnbApp\pnbApp\MainActivity.cs  29  Active

This is the part it is failing on in code:

```
> public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
>         {
>             public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
>             {
>                 view.LoadUrl(url);
>                 return true;
>             }
>         }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It is just a warning that means `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)` is obsolete, and is is deprecated in API level 24. Using `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` instead.

If you are targeting android older versions , you need the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)`, and if you are targeting 24 or later it's advisable to override the latter method as well. But the former method `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)` is still working in the API level 24

code example:

```
public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            //Uri uri = Uri.Parse(url);
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            Uri url = request.Url;
            view.LoadUrl(url.ToString());
            return true;
        }
    }
```